# "table or subquery expected, got " error in Android Room

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm, android-room

I'm writing a database for keeping information about words in Android application with Room. I've built two entities: Group and VocaNote. Between Group and VocaNote I use one-to-many relationship to keep array of VocaNote in separate groups.

**Group class**

```
@Entity(indices = {
    @Index(value = {"language", "nameGroup"}, unique = true)
}
)
public class Group {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public long id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "language")
public String language;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name_group")
public String nameGroup;
}
```

**VocaNote class**

```
    @Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Group.class,
    parentColumns = "id",
    childColumns = "group_id",
    onDelete = CASCADE))
  public class VocaNote {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public long id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "origin_word")
public String originWord;

@ColumnInfo(name = "translation")
public String translation;

@ColumnInfo(name = "studied_word")
public int studied;

@ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
public int groupId;
```

}

After that I've added separate DAOs for above entity classes like that

**VocaNoteDao**

```
@Dao
public interface VocaNoteDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM vocanote")
List<VocaNote> getAllVocaNote();

@Query("SELECT * FROM vocanote WHERE id = :id")
VocaNote getByIdVocaNote(long id);

@Insert
void insert(VocaNote vocaNote);

@Update
void update(VocaNote vocaNote);

@Delete
void delete (VocaNote vocaNote);
}
```

**GroupDao**

```
@Dao
public interface GroupDao {
@Insert
void insert(Group group);

@Update
void update(Group group);

@Delete
void delete (Group group);

@Query("SELECT * FROM group")
List<Group> getAllGroup();

@Query("SELECT * FROM group WHERE id = :id")
Group getByIdGroup(long id);
```

}

And here I got a problem. When I'm trying to make queries from group table, but instead recieve compile error **table or subquery expected, got group**.
Please tell me, how I can deal with that? I have group entity but my IDE doesn't want to see it/

Comment: You may need to supply a separate `tableName` for `Group`, as `GROUP` is a SQL reserved keyword.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Your comment helped to solve my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

Use brackets to escape reserved keyword

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM [group] WHERE id = :id")
Group getByIdGroup(long id);
```

Comment: While this will work, single quotes might be better—see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html for details.

Answer (score -1):

You must check for the Table name. It's mandatory to write table name.Not even a empty string.